# PC won't shut down and won't recognize USB devices after RAM Overclocking

Tags: overclocking

I have an ASUS Z170-K + i7 6700 and yesterday I overclocked the RAM memory to make it work at 3000MHz (stock RAM frequency) because was capped at 2133MHz.

I loaded the XMP preset profile with CPU at 1.35V, changed the PCIe speed from auto to Gen2 and disabled VTd.

After that i rebooted and the American Megatrend BIOS appeared with "NO keyboard detected", and I noticed USB 3.0 devices were not recognized neither in BIOS nor in Windows, so i had to use mouse and keyboard in USB 2.0 ports.

First I thought  I broke the USB 3.0 controller, but then I reset the CMOS by the pins on the motherboard and USB 3.0 ports were working so it was fine, but not 2.0 devices this time.

I also tried to install drivers from official website, reset CMOS again, reset default settings in BIOS, remove CMOS battery but nothing changed.

Moreover, since I had this problem the PC won't shut down completely so i have to press the power button to shut down completely.

Comment: Please edit your question and say exactly where the USB devices do not work, at boot time or in Windows 10?